# Detect URL change (including hashchange) in Firefox AddOn

Tags: javascript, hash, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, hashchange

Is there any event I can subscribe to, and how, to be able to monitor URL change (including hash change)?
Currently I do this with an setInterval() method, and check every second if URL has changed...
But there must be some more efficient way I suppose?

I know in Javascript there is window.onhashchange event, but how do I get reference to window inside my AddOn code?

Also, I have tried using the

```
tabs.on('ready'....
```

and it reacts to URL change, but not to hash change :(

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: [Detect tab url change inside firefox add-on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464941/detect-tab-url-change-inside-firefox-add-on). Please indicate if that does not solve your issue.

Comment: In order to tell you how to get a reference to `window` in your add-on code we need to know which window, or windows you are attempting to get access to. Are you wanting to set up a listener for `hashcode` on every tab in every window? Do you want to do so only for a specific `tab` to which you already have a reference? We need more information. A [mcve] of what you are doing now would significantly help in understanding exactly what you are wanting to do.